Looking for clear, motivated proofs of "Exponentiation is Diophantine"
I'm working through Matiyasevich's "Hilbert's Tenth Problem" (1993) and Jones and Matiyasevich's "Recursive Unsolvability of Hilbert's Tenth Problem" (1991) to try to understand the proof that exponentiation is Diophantine.
The former does a pretty good job of motivating the steps of the construction, but I'm having trouble following fully towards the end. Specifically, Matiyasevich is looking at the Lucas sequence: $$\alpha_b(0) = 0, \qquad \alpha_b(1) = 1, \qquad \alpha_b(n+2) = b \cdot \alpha_b(n+1) - \alpha_b(n),$$
Proving that the set of tuples $(n,b,\alpha_b(n))$ is Diophantine first, and it's this step that I'm having trouble following.
Can anyone recommend other proofs that exponentiation is Diophantine that do a good job of not just spelling out the steps of the proof/construction but also explaining why the steps are taken?

I don't remember details, but I believe Martin Davis once wrote an expository paper about the solution of Hilbert's 10th problem. I think it included a proof about exponentiation, not using Fibonacci numbers (as the original proof did) but properties of Pell equations.
